# Screen distorted, has greenish tint and does not boot completely after the Apple logo and progress bar loads

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup, crash

My Macbook Pro 2011 hung so I forced restarted it but on restart the screen was bit distorted and had greenish tint (Picture below) also it never goes past the Apple logo and progress bar to boot completely. I tried to launch the recovery mode but I couldn't find a way to do it with reFind installed.
Has anybody here faced this issue or know how to fix this?

reFind Boot menu

[image: Mac book - reFind boot loader menu]

Apple logo with progress bar (Progress bar distorted)

[image]

After this screen I see blank gray screen then Mac shuts down abruptly on its own.
Macbook is running OS X Yosemite and is 2011 model.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GPU problem - Boot Hangs on Grey Screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267581/gpu-problem-boot-hangs-on-grey-screen)

Answer (score 0):

Since your MBP is a 2011 model, the chance is that it is affected by faulty descrete AMD GPU. Almost all the Early and Late 2011 MBPs with descrete GPU are affected by this. I too had the same issue with my MBP and was fixed by Apple for free. It has been 9 months since the fix and it seems to be ok.

Apple has already issued a free replacement program for faulty logicboards in February 2015 till February 2016. Better you hurry and go to nearest Apple Store or Apple Authorized Service Center. Find more details in the link below.

[Apple MacBook Pro video issues](http://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/)

Answer (score 0):

## 0. If you are already using a boot manager / boot loader it is possible to circumvent this problem

[This](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4766577?start=510&tstart=0) [fun](https://9to5mac.com/2014/10/28/apple-class-action-lawsuit-2011-macbook-pro-gpu-graphics-issues/comment-page-1/) [situation](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5958077?start=15&tstart=0) is [most](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qltsqZpNHek) [likely](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecEPLYbjXXU) the [infamous](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/booting-a-radeongate-affected-mbp.1722557/) [Apple-AMD](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4637833?start=0&tstart=0) RadeonGate [failure](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4637833?start=0&tstart=0) of the [discrete](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WlpZH1tQtF8) [graphics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WlpZH1tQtF8) [chip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WlpZH1tQtF8). The [repair extension program has ended](https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/) for [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1AcEt073Uds) machines. [Apple refuses now to repair such a machine](https://support.apple.com/en-mo/HT201624) at all and prohibits Apple Authorized Service Providers from [repairing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVAmnV65_zw) them.

The solution posted below is a suitable approach if the machine in question already uses a foreign boot-loader.

A purely Mac-only and easily reversible software solution is available [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295805/251859) (that solution has the advantage of resulting in better battery life.) This solution here makes the discrete GPU completely invisible to the operating system.

This has the advantage of giving 100% reliable sleep and shutdown behaviour. The disadvantage of this approach detailed below is that it uses more power overall and after the first waking from sleep the dGPU uses even more power than is good for battery life.
In any case, using an external display via Thunderbolt will be disabled as well.

Note that the solution below assumes that GRUB chainloads macOS. The solution below is *not* only for dual boot [installation with Linux](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/257014/251859). It works perfectly well by only booting macOS from an isolated instance of GRUB. Linux is only needed to set this up, not for daily use. Ubuntu is only one of possible choices used below as a popular example.

> ## 1. Disable SIP
>
> If you can boot into Single User Recovery Mode <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>,  and enter:
>
> ```
> csrutil disable
> ```
>
> If you can’t, create a USB stick with rEFInd as described here:
>   http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/sip.html#disable_in_refind
>
> ## 2. Change the gpu-power-prefs
>
> Boot into single user mode <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> and change the
>   gpu-power-prefs nvram variable:
>
> ```
> sudo nvram fa4ce28d-b62f-4c99-9cc3-6815686e30f9:gpu-power-prefs=%01%00%00%00
> reboot
> ```
>
> [This step is listed in this way in case Recovery Mode is unavailable. The command may issued there as well.]
>
> ## 3. Create a rescue thumb drive
>
> In this step we will create a rescue thumb drive that you can use
>   every time you are having trouble booting macOS.
>
> ### 3.1. Download ubuntu iso
>
> http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.10/ubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso
>
> ### 3.2. Mount the iso
>
> On Windows (7 and later) or Ubuntu should be straight forward (you
>   just need to double click the iso). On macOS, assuming you have the
>   iso in the Downloads folder, run the following command on the
>   terminal:
>
> ```
> hdiutil attach -nomount ~/Downloads/ubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso
> ```
>
> Which should return something like:
>
> ```
> /dev/disk2            Apple_partition_scheme          
> /dev/disk2s1          Apple_partition_map             
> /dev/disk2s2          Apple_HFS
> ```
>
> Then run the following commands to mount and open the iso disk (in my
>   case `/dev/disk2`)
>
> ```
> mkdir /tmp/ubuntu 
> mount -t cd9660 /dev/disk2 /tmp/ubuntu/
> open /tmp/ubuntu/
> ```
>
> ### 3.3. Format and copy the files
>
> Format your thumb drive as FAT32 and name it `RESCUE`, then copy the
>   `EFI` and `boot` folders from the iso to your thumb drive.
>
> ### 3.4. Edit the grub.cfg file
>
> On your thumb drive, open the file at `boot/grub/grub.cfg` with any
>   text editor and change it to:
>
> ```
>  menuentry "macOS" {
>     insmod hfsplus
>     outb 0x728 1
>     outb 0x710 2
>     outb 0x740 2
>     outb 0x750 0
>     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root <YOUR UUID>
>     chainloader /System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi
> }
> ```
>
> ### 3.5. Boot you mac with the thumb drive
>
> Boot your mac and when you hear the chimes, press and hold `Option
>   (alt)` and then choose your thumb drive.
>
> Then when grub appears press `c` and run the command:
>
> ```
> ls -l
> ```
>
> A list of partitions should appear. Take note of the UUID for your
>   macOS partition.
>
> Press `ESC` and then `e` to edit macOS menu entry and then replace
>   `<YOUR UUID>` with the uuid of your partition.
>
> Press `fn F10` to boot.
>
> Your macOS should now boot normally.
>
> ### 3.6. Change the uuid on grub.cfg
>
> On your thumb drive, open the file at `boot/grub/grub.cfg` with any
>   text editor and replace `<YOUR UUID>` with the uuid you got on the
>   step 3.5.
>
> You can now boot from the thumb drive without having to change the
>   uuid every time.
>
> ## 4. Make it permanent
>
> In this step we will make the macOS boot without the thumb drive.
>
> After booting macOS with your thumb drive and with it still plugged,
>   open the terminal and run the following commands (I will assume your
>   thumb drive name is `RESCUE`, if not, replace `RESCUE` with your thumb
>   drive name):
>
> ```
> cd /Volumes
> sudo mkdir efi
> sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/efi
> sudo mkdir /Volumes/efi/boot
> sudo mkdir /Volumes/efi/EFI/grub
> sudo cp -R /Volumes/RESCUE/boot/ /Volumes/efi/boot
> sudo cp -R /Volumes/RESCUE/EFI/boot/ /Volumes/efi/EFI/grub
> sudo bless --folder=/Volumes/efi --file=/Volumes/efi/EFI/grub/grubx64.efi --setBoot
> sudo bless --mount=/Volumes/efi --file=/Volumes/efi/EFI/grub/grubx64.efi --setBoot
> ```
>
> You are now able to boot without the thumb drive.
>
> ## 5. Recover when macOS updates
>
> Everytime macOS updates, you need to bless grub again. For this, you
>   need to boot with your rescue thumb drive, and then on macOS terminal
>   run the following commands:
>
> ```
> cd /Volumes
> sudo mkdir efi
> sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/efi
> sudo bless --folder=/Volumes/efi --file=/Volumes/efi/EFI/grub/grubx64.efi --setBoot
> sudo bless --mount=/Volumes/efi --file=/Volumes/efi/EFI/grub/grubx64.efi --setBoot
> ```

Inspiration for this solution is found [here](https://gist.github.com/blackgate/17ac402e35d2f7e0f1c9708db3dc7a44).